# React render component using its name

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am experimenting React.js and it is working really well. I am wondering if it is possible to inject classes to other classes like so:

```
var Container = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
      <{this.props.implComponent}/>
    }
});
```

Assuming implComponent has been passed like so:

```
React.render(
  <Container implComponent="somePredefinedVariable" />,
   document.getElementById('content')
);
```

This does not work because of a Syntax error. I can easily understand why.

In other words I'd like to inject classes to other classes based on names. Is this possible? How can I do that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You were close.  You need to pass the component class it self (not a string), and then because the tag syntax takes a variable already, you get rid of the `{}`s.  Also don't forget to return the node from render.

```
var Container = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <this.props.implComponent />
    }
});

React.render(
  <Container implComponent={SomePredefinedVariable} />,
   document.getElementById('content')
);
```

If you want to pass a basic dom component, you'd use a string

This makes sense if you think about the transform result

```
var Container = React.createClass({displayName: "Container",
    render: function() {
      return React.createElement(this.props.implComponent, null)
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement(Container, {implComponent: SomePredefinedVariable}),
   document.getElementById('content')
);
```

```
ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement(Container, {implComponent: "div"}),
   document.getElementById('content')
);
```